# Mostrar datos en un Textbox con C# y WPF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wpf, xaml

Espero poder explicarme bien, para que puedan ayudarme con el problemita que estoy presentando. (Tratare de resumir!).

Resulta que estoy empezando en la construcción de una desktop app con wpf (siguiendo un [curso de pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=wpf-mvvm-entity-framework-app&author=thomas-huber&name=wpf-mvvm-entity-framework-app-m6&clip=4&mode=live)).

Tengo hecho tres proyectos:
**1. DataAccess** para la conexión a la BD(SQL Server)
**2. Model** para las clases POCO, modelos de entidades y Views que mostraran los datos
**3. IU**, aca aplico el patrón MVVM y toda la lógica del programa.

Estoy usando dos controles de usuarios personalizados,en uno muestro la lista de "Amigos(Friends)" con los que estoy trabajando, y en el otro muestro los detalles de cada usuario en TextBoxes. 
Resulta que en el XAML de la MainWindow tengo dos tags donde uso el Binding referenciando el DataContext a mis dos controles de usuario personalizados.
Luego en el XAML de cada control:

***Para el Primero**(La Lista) tengo un tag ListView donde uso Binding para la clase ViewModel que me genera la lista (de Friends) en formato LookupItem(otra clase modelo que muestra solo Nombre y Apellido)

***Para el Segundo** tengo tres controles TextBox(con sus respectivos Labels indicando que datos se mostraran en cada uno), donde uso Binding a una Propiedad de tipo "Friend"(Clase POCO, la cual tiene los atributos: Nombre(FirstName), Apellido(LastName), Email).

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <view:NavigationView DataContext="{Binding NavigationViewModel}"/>
    <view:FriendDetailView DataContext="{Binding FriendDetailViewModel}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

**El PROBLEMA.** al inciar la aplicacion estoy usando inyección de dependencias de la siguiente forma:

```
 public IContainer Bootstrap()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>().As<IEventAggregator>().SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<FriendOrganizerDBContext>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<NavigationViewModel>().As<INavigationViewModel>();
        builder.RegisterType<FriendDetailViewModel>().As<IFriendDetailViewModel>();

        builder.RegisterType<LookupDataService>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterType<FriendDataService>().As<IFriendDataService>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

y la ventana se muestra sin problemas, incluyendo la lista (LookupItems: Nombre + Apellido) de cada uno de los "Amigos", pero cuando selecciono un "Amigo" para que se muestren los detalles de éste en los TextBoxes, no se actualiza el atributo Text del TexBox correspondiente....
Cabe destacar que al hacer el Binding del atributo Text en el TextBox lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding Friend.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, 
             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10 0 10 10"/>
```

*Revise si la conexión al DBContext estaba mal, y no!
*Revise si habia alguna otra propiedad prodiga dentro del código, con el mismo nombre a la que le estoy haciendo el binding, y no!
*Revise si habia escrito mal algún nombre de alguna propiedad o método de forma que no estuviese haciendo la referencia correcta a la implementación del mismo o de la misma, y no!
*El IDE(Visual Studio Community 2019) tampoco me lanza ningun error de sintaxis, ni de referencias mal hechas a algún método.

Dejo los códigos de las clases **VIEWMODEL** que corresponden a la lista de Amigos y a los detalles de cada Amigo que buscan los datos desde la clase `DbContext`. ¡Para que puedan ver si me estoy saltando algo!

```
public class NavigationViewModel : ViewModelBase, INavigationViewModel
{
    private IFriendLookupDataService _friendLookupDataService;
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public NavigationViewModel(IFriendLookupDataService friendLookupDataService,
        IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _friendLookupDataService = friendLookupDataService;
        Friends = new ObservableCollection<LookupItem>();

        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public async Task LoadAsync()
    {
        var lookup = await _friendLookupDataService.GetFriendLookupAsync();
        Friends.Clear();
        foreach (var friendLookup in lookup)
        {
            Friends.Add(friendLookup);
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<LookupItem> Friends { get; }

    private LookupItem _selectedFriend;

    public LookupItem SelectedFriend
    {
        get { return _selectedFriend; }
        set
        {
            _selectedFriend = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            if(_selectedFriend!=null)
            {
                _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenFriendDetailViewEvent>()
                .Publish(_selectedFriend.Id);
            }
        }
    }

}

 public class FriendDetailViewModel : ViewModelBase, IFriendDetailViewModel
{
    private IFriendDataService _dataService;
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public FriendDetailViewModel(IFriendDataService dataService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenFriendDetailViewEvent>()
            .Subscribe(OnOpenFriendDetailViewEvent);
    }
    public Friend Friend
    {
        get { return _friend; }
        set
        {
            _friend = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private async void OnOpenFriendDetailViewEvent(int friendId)
    {
        await LoadAsync(friendId);
    }

    public async Task LoadAsync(int friendId)
    {
        Friend = await _dataService.GetByIdAsync(friendId);
    }

    private Friend _friend;

}
```

Llevo una semana con el problema y no consigo solución aún. Ayuda! De antemano, muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: developLelu, intenta solo publicar la parte importante del codigo porque pocos miraremos todo el codigo. Te recomendaria tambien crear un proyecto de prueba e intentar reproducir el escenario con datos harcode a ver si te funciona.

Comment: En ningún momento hablas de la gestión del comando que debe lanzar el control `ListView` cuando cambia la selección de un `item` del cual deberías recoger los datos del `Amigo` seleccionado y que éste debería cargar los datos en los `TextBox`. Esto en MVVM se realiza meidante `ICommand` relacionándolo con la propiedad `Command` del control, algo como esto: `Command="{Binding MostrarDetallesCommand}"`... no se si me explico

Comment: Gracias a ambos por las respuestas!...me di cuenta de cual es el verdadero problema. Tengo una propiedad Friend que se actualiza con INotifyPropertyChanged en el set de la misma, pero cuando se debe ejecutar el get para obtener los datos nunca entra a esa parte del codigo, no lo ejecuta el programa. No se si me explico....Lo que me dices sobre ICommand lo entiendo, pero deberia ejecutarse sin implementarlo, ya que como mencione estoy siguiendo un curso en pluralsight y he seguido estrictamente los pasos, y al "instructor" se le ejecuta el programa normalmente sin implementar ICommand...